# JSON read 4700 records from database

Tags: android, json

My android application use this code for to read and import 4700 records from mysql database on the web with JSONArray :

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/preleva_prodotti.php");       
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                //Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+ e.toString());
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                return result = "no_server";
            }

            //convert response to string
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                String k = reader.readLine();
                while ((line = k) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb;
            }catch(Exception e){
                return result = "no_server";
            }
            //parse json data
            try{
                JSONObject json= new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("array");
                            return is_full="ok_insert";
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                return is_full = "no_dati";
            }
        }
```

but at the line :

```
while ((line = k) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

there is the error : **Out of Memory**.
How can resolve this problem?

Comment: In your code, you tried to store all json text in string object, and then start parsing it to json. Some json library (jackson, gson) supports streaming parsing. So I think streaming parsing can solve your memory problem. With streaming parsing, you can start parsing json no need to all data in memory.

Comment: How about not import 4700 records at a time, you maybe using up all the memory for the app or on the phone.  I would query it in chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Java, so bear with me, but this seems to be language-agnostic.

That said, the problem appears to be that `k` is never updated. Once `k` is assigned (`k = reader.readLine()`) you're (indefinitely) re-assigning `line` that *same* value (thus infinite loop, thus out of memory).

I think you're looking for:

```
            String k = reader.readLine();
            while ((line = k) != null) {
              sb.append(line + "\n");
              k = reader.readLine(); // or some facsimile
            }
```

Note that I now re-assign `k` (though I'm not sure the redundancy of having `k` = `line`; seems like a waste of a variable, imho)

Comment: Unless, somehow, `k` becomes synonymous with calling `reader.readLine()`, that's the problem that I see...

Comment: no, the problem is in line sb.append because k is too longer for StringBuilder but I don't know how can resolve this problem....

Comment: You're positive it's that `line` has too large a value, and not that `sb` has hit its buffer threshold?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that one line of the file exceeds the capacity of the `Append` method but I'll take your word for it. With that said, I would check out [this article](http://mohammed-technical.blogspot.com/2010/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-with.html) on avoiding it using streams.

Comment: @Brad is correct, you have an infinite loop in that code, you will get an oom error reading a 1 line json file like that.

Comment: I think that line but also JSONObject not support this value too large...I must try another code...